Conversion to Java of a Delphi algorithm for CRC checksum for file
I was given this Delphi code:
unit lib_CRC;
interface uses SysUtils;
function CalculateCRC(Text: String): String;
implementation{ CRC Code generation routines }

const{: @summary CRC Code generation array }
CRCTable : array [0..255] of Cardinal = 
(
    $00000000, $77073096, $ee0e612c, $990951ba,
    $076dc419, $706af48f, $e963a535, $9e6495a3,
    $0edb8832, $79dcb8a4, $e0d5e91e, $97d2d988,
    $09b64c2b, $7eb17cbd, $e7b82d07, $90bf1d91,

    $1db71064, $6ab020f2, $f3b97148, $84be41de,
    $1adad47d, $6ddde4eb, $f4d4b551, $83d385c7,
    $136c9856, $646ba8c0, $fd62f97a, $8a65c9ec,
    $14015c4f, $63066cd9, $fa0f3d63, $8d080df5,

    $3b6e20c8, $4c69105e, $d56041e4, $a2677172,
    $3c03e4d1, $4b04d447, $d20d85fd, $a50ab56b,
    $35b5a8fa, $42b2986c, $dbbbc9d6, $acbcf940,
    $32d86ce3, $45df5c75, $dcd60dcf, $abd13d59,

    $26d930ac, $51de003a, $c8d75180, $bfd06116,
    $21b4f4b5, $56b3c423, $cfba9599, $b8bda50f,
    $2802b89e, $5f058808, $c60cd9b2, $b10be924,
    $2f6f7c87, $58684c11, $c1611dab, $b6662d3d,

    $76dc4190,  $01db7106, $98d220bc,   $efd5102a,
    $71b18589, $06b6b51f, $9fbfe4a5, $e8b8d433,
    $7807c9a2, $0f00f934, $9609a88e, $e10e9818,
    $7f6a0dbb, $086d3d2d, $91646c97, $e6635c01,

    $6b6b51f4, $1c6c6162, $856530d8, $f262004e,
    $6c0695ed, $1b01a57b, $8208f4c1, $f50fc457,
    $65b0d9c6, $12b7e950, $8bbeb8ea, $fcb9887c,
    $62dd1ddf, $15da2d49, $8cd37cf3, $fbd44c65,

    $4db26158, $3ab551ce, $a3bc0074, $d4bb30e2,
    $4adfa541, $3dd895d7, $a4d1c46d, $d3d6f4fb, 
    $4369e96a, $346ed9fc, $ad678846, $da60b8d0,
    $44042d73, $33031de5, $aa0a4c5f, $dd0d7cc9,

    $5005713c, $270241aa, $be0b1010, $c90c2086,
    $5768b525, $206f85b3, $b966d409, $ce61e49f,
    $5edef90e, $29d9c998, $b0d09822, $c7d7a8b4,
    $59b33d17, $2eb40d81, $b7bd5c3b, $c0ba6cad,

    $edb88320, $9abfb3b6, $03b6e20c, $74b1d29a,
    $ead54739, $9dd277af, $04db2615, $73dc1683,
    $e3630b12, $94643b84, $0d6d6a3e, $7a6a5aa8,
    $e40ecf0b, $9309ff9d, $0a00ae27, $7d079eb1,

    $f00f9344, $8708a3d2, $1e01f268, $6906c2fe,
    $f762575d, $806567cb,   $196c3671, $6e6b06e7,
    $fed41b76, $89d32be0, $10da7a5a, $67dd4acc,
    $f9b9df6f, $8ebeeff9, $17b7be43, $60b08ed5,

    $d6d6a3e8, $a1d1937e, $38d8c2c4, $4fdff252,
    $d1bb67f1, $a6bc5767, $3fb506dd, $48b2364b,
    $d80d2bda, $af0a1b4c, $36034af6, $41047a60,
    $df60efc3,  $a867df55, $316e8eef, $4669be79,

    $cb61b38c, $bc66831a, $256fd2a0, $5268e236,
    $cc0c7795, $bb0b4703, $220216b9, $5505262f,
    $c5ba3bbe, $b2bd0b28, $2bb45a92, $5cb36a04,
    $c2d7ffa7, $b5d0cf31, $2cd99e8b, $5bdeae1d,

    $9b64c2b0, $ec63f226, $756aa39c, $026d930a,
    $9c0906a9, $eb0e363f, $72076785, $05005713,
    $95bf4a82, $e2b87a14, $7bb12bae, $0cb61b38,
    $92d28e9b, $e5d5be0d, $7cdcefb7, $0bdbdf21,

    $86d3d2d4, $f1d4e242, $68ddb3f8, $1fda836e,
    $81be16cd, $f6b9265b, $6fb077e1, $18b74777,
    $88085ae6, $ff0f6a70, $66063bca, $11010b5c,
    $8f659eff, $f862ae69, $616bffd3, $166ccf45,

    $a00ae278, $d70dd2ee, $4e048354, $3903b3c2,
    $a7672661, $d06016f7, $4969474d, $3e6e77db,
    $aed16a4a, $d9d65adc, $40df0b66, $37d83bf0,
    $a9bcae53, $debb9ec5, $47b2cf7f, $30b5ffe9,

    $bdbdf21c, $cabac28a, $53b39330, $24b4a3a6,
    $bad03605, $cdd70693, $54de5729, $23d967bf,
    $b3667a2e, $c4614ab8, $5d681b02, $2a6f2b94,
    $b40bbe37, $c30c8ea1, $5a05df1b, $2d02ef8d
);


{: @summary CRC Codegeneration routine }
function CalculateCRC(Text: String): String ;
var Index  : Integer;
    CRCVal : Cardinal;

begin
    CRCVal:=0;
    for Index:=1 to Length(Text)
    do CRCVal:=CRCTable[Byte(CRCVal xor Ord(Text[Index]))] xor((CRCVal shr 8) and $00FFFFFF);
    Result:=UpperCase(IntToHex(CRCVal, 8));
end;
end.

For which I have produced my correspondent Java code:
package com.noemalife.hal.communication.test.drivers;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class LyrasCRC {

    private static final int[] CRC_TABLE = {
                        0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xee0e612c, 0x990951ba,
                        0x076dc419, 0x706af48f, 0xe963a535, 0x9e6495a3,
                        0x0edb8832, 0x79dcb8a4, 0xe0d5e91e, 0x97d2d988,
                        0x09b64c2b, 0x7eb17cbd, 0xe7b82d07, 0x90bf1d91,
                        
                        0x1db71064, 0x6ab020f2, 0xf3b97148, 0x84be41de,
                        0x1adad47d, 0x6ddde4eb, 0xf4d4b551, 0x83d385c7,
                        0x136c9856, 0x646ba8c0, 0xfd62f97a, 0x8a65c9ec,
                        0x14015c4f, 0x63066cd9, 0xfa0f3d63, 0x8d080df5,
                        
                        0x3b6e20c8, 0x4c69105e, 0xd56041e4, 0xa2677172,
                        0x3c03e4d1, 0x4b04d447, 0xd20d85fd, 0xa50ab56b,
                        0x35b5a8fa, 0x42b2986c, 0xdbbbc9d6, 0xacbcf940,
                        0x32d86ce3, 0x45df5c75, 0xdcd60dcf, 0xabd13d59,
                        
                        0x26d930ac, 0x51de003a, 0xc8d75180, 0xbfd06116,
                        0x21b4f4b5, 0x56b3c423, 0xcfba9599, 0xb8bda50f,
                        0x2802b89e, 0x5f058808, 0xc60cd9b2, 0xb10be924,
                        0x2f6f7c87, 0x58684c11, 0xc1611dab, 0xb6662d3d,
                        
                        0x76dc4190, 0x01db7106, 0x98d220bc, 0xefd5102a,
                        0x71b18589, 0x06b6b51f, 0x9fbfe4a5, 0xe8b8d433,
                        0x7807c9a2, 0x0f00f934, 0x9609a88e, 0xe10e9818,
                        0x7f6a0dbb, 0x086d3d2d, 0x91646c97, 0xe6635c01,
                        
                        0x6b6b51f4, 0x1c6c6162, 0x856530d8, 0xf262004e,
                        0x6c0695ed, 0x1b01a57b, 0x8208f4c1, 0xf50fc457,
                        0x65b0d9c6, 0x12b7e950, 0x8bbeb8ea, 0xfcb9887c,
                        0x62dd1ddf, 0x15da2d49, 0x8cd37cf3, 0xfbd44c65,
                        
                        0x4db26158, 0x3ab551ce, 0xa3bc0074, 0xd4bb30e2,
                        0x4adfa541, 0x3dd895d7, 0xa4d1c46d, 0xd3d6f4fb, 
                        0x4369e96a, 0x346ed9fc, 0xad678846, 0xda60b8d0,
                        0x44042d73, 0x33031de5, 0xaa0a4c5f, 0xdd0d7cc9,
                        
                        0x5005713c, 0x270241aa, 0xbe0b1010, 0xc90c2086,
                        0x5768b525, 0x206f85b3, 0xb966d409, 0xce61e49f,
                        0x5edef90e, 0x29d9c998, 0xb0d09822, 0xc7d7a8b4,
                        0x59b33d17, 0x2eb40d81, 0xb7bd5c3b, 0xc0ba6cad,
                        
                        0xedb88320, 0x9abfb3b6, 0x03b6e20c, 0x74b1d29a,
                        0xead54739, 0x9dd277af, 0x04db2615, 0x73dc1683,
                        0xe3630b12, 0x94643b84, 0x0d6d6a3e, 0x7a6a5aa8,
                        0xe40ecf0b, 0x9309ff9d, 0x0a00ae27, 0x7d079eb1,
                        
                        0xf00f9344, 0x8708a3d2, 0x1e01f268, 0x6906c2fe,
                        0xf762575d, 0x806567cb, 0x196c3671, 0x6e6b06e7,
                        0xfed41b76, 0x89d32be0, 0x10da7a5a, 0x67dd4acc,
                        0xf9b9df6f, 0x8ebeeff9, 0x17b7be43, 0x60b08ed5,
                        
                        0xd6d6a3e8, 0xa1d1937e, 0x38d8c2c4, 0x4fdff252,
                        0xd1bb67f1, 0xa6bc5767, 0x3fb506dd, 0x48b2364b,
                        0xd80d2bda, 0xaf0a1b4c, 0x36034af6, 0x41047a60,
                        0xdf60efc3, 0xa867df55, 0x316e8eef, 0x4669be79,
                        
                        0xcb61b38c, 0xbc66831a, 0x256fd2a0, 0x5268e236,
                        0xcc0c7795, 0xbb0b4703, 0x220216b9, 0x5505262f,
                        0xc5ba3bbe, 0xb2bd0b28, 0x2bb45a92, 0x5cb36a04,
                        0xc2d7ffa7, 0xb5d0cf31, 0x2cd99e8b, 0x5bdeae1d,
                        
                        0x9b64c2b0, 0xec63f226, 0x756aa39c, 0x026d930a,
                        0x9c0906a9, 0xeb0e363f, 0x72076785, 0x05005713,
                        0x95bf4a82, 0xe2b87a14, 0x7bb12bae, 0x0cb61b38,
                        0x92d28e9b, 0xe5d5be0d, 0x7cdcefb7, 0x0bdbdf21,
                        
                        0x86d3d2d4, 0xf1d4e242, 0x68ddb3f8, 0x1fda836e,
                        0x81be16cd, 0xf6b9265b, 0x6fb077e1, 0x18b74777,
                        0x88085ae6, 0xff0f6a70, 0x66063bca, 0x11010b5c,
                        0x8f659eff, 0xf862ae69, 0x616bffd3, 0x166ccf45,
                        
                        0xa00ae278, 0xd70dd2ee, 0x4e048354, 0x3903b3c2,
                        0xa7672661, 0xd06016f7, 0x4969474d, 0x3e6e77db,
                        0xaed16a4a, 0xd9d65adc, 0x40df0b66, 0x37d83bf0,
                        0xa9bcae53, 0xdebb9ec5, 0x47b2cf7f, 0x30b5ffe9,
                        
                        0xbdbdf21c, 0xcabac28a, 0x53b39330, 0x24b4a3a6,
                        0xbad03605, 0xcdd70693, 0x54de5729, 0x23d967bf,
                        0xb3667a2e, 0xc4614ab8, 0x5d681b02, 0x2a6f2b94,
                        0xb40bbe37, 0xc30c8ea1, 0x5a05df1b, 0x2d02ef8d};

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File("C:\\...").toPath());
        System.out.println(calculateLyrasCRC(bytes));
    }
        
    public static String calculateLyrasCRC(byte[] text) {
        int crcValue = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<text.length; i++) {
            crcValue = CRC_TABLE[(crcValue ^ text[i])] ^ ((crcValue >> 8) & 0x00FFFFFF);
        }
        String crcValueStr = Integer.toHexString(crcValue).toUpperCase();
        return crcValueStr;
    }
}

The ouput of that CRC calculation must be appended at the end of the file before being sent.
Anyway, the procedure fails: after one or two iterations it seems to generate a big negative number used to access the CRC_TABLE for which I get a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
I have seen these examples:
Example in C
Example in C#
but I cannot get the difference, except in the use of the final XOR. Do you have any ideas where I am making the mistake?
POSSIBLE SOLUTION
As suggested by @g00se and @Matthias B a working solution may be
crcValue = CRC_TABLE[(crcValue ^ text[i]) & 0xFF] ^ ((crcValue >> 8) & 0x00FFFFFF);
I've said "may be" because actually I have no possibility nor feedback to verify if the calculated value is logically correct

Try crcValue = CRC_TABLE[(crcValue ^ text[i]) & 0xFF] ^ ((crcValue >> 8) & 0x00FFFFFF);

btw, you know Java already has java.util.zip.CRC32? Also, you never want to bind your implementation to reading the input whole into memory

@g00se: yes, I had tried that class and it seemed to work but I haven't understood exactly if the implementation of that class was right according to the Deplhi code I have to replicate (as there is CRC32, CRC16 and so many variants). Regarding the loading of file into memory you are right but our workflow will exchange files of little dimensions (< 10KB) and unfortunately, because of how our product works, I will receive the file already loaded into memory when my procedure of the CRC algorithm is to be called

Well of course, if, for some reason, the output is required to match that of the Delphi (happy memories) implementation then you should use yours with the change I suggested. Of course you're going to have to test it against the original too. The Java CRC32 output is the same as the GNU crc32, which is not the same as yours

Again thank you for you kind and precious help!

The Java code is missing the type cast to Byte that the Delphi code has.
The type cast to Byte truncates the value so that it always stays in the 0-255 range, which fits what the array needs to be indexed by.
Note that in Delphi, Byte is an unsigned 8-bit number, while Java's byte data type is signed, so you cannot use Java's byte directly. I believe that the way to truncate an integer to an unsigned byte in Java is by taking (value & 0xFF).
